# Fill NA values over varied data frame column slices in Pandas

Tags: python, pandas

I have a Pandas data frame similar to the following:

```
pd.DataFrame({
    'End' : ['2022-03','2022-05','2022-06'],
    '2022-01' : [1,2,np.nan],
    '2022-02' : [np.nan,3,4],
    '2022-03' : [np.nan,1,3],
    '2022-04' : [np.nan,np.nan,2],
    '2022-05' : [np.nan,np.nan,np.nan],
    '2022-06' : [np.nan,np.nan,np.nan]
})
```

I would like to fill the NaN values in each row such that all columns up to that listed in `end` are replaced with 0 while those after remain as NaN

The desired output would be:

```
pd.DataFrame({
    'End' : ['2022-03','2022-05','2022-06'],
    '2022-01' : [1,2,0],
    '2022-02' : [0,3,4],
    '2022-03' : [0,1,3],
    '2022-04' : [np.nan,0,2],
    '2022-05' : [np.nan,0,0],
    '2022-06' : [np.nan,np.nan,0]
})
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use numpy broadcasting on the index/columns with [`mask`](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.mask.html) and [`fillna`](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.fillna.html):

```
mask = df['End'].to_numpy()[:, None] >= df.columns.to_numpy()

out = df.fillna(df.mask(mask, 0))

print(out)
```

Output:

```
       End  2022-01  2022-02  2022-03  2022-04  2022-05  2022-06
0  2022-03      1.0      0.0      0.0      NaN      NaN      NaN
1  2022-05      2.0      3.0      1.0      0.0      0.0      NaN
2  2022-06      0.0      4.0      3.0      2.0      0.0      0.0
```

Intermediate `mask`:

```
array([[ True,  True, False, False, False, False],
       [ True,  True,  True,  True, False, False],
       [ True,  True,  True,  True,  True, False]])
```

Answer (score 2):

Use broadcasting to compare the months, then you can mask with `where`:

```
df.iloc[:,1:] = df.iloc[:,1:].fillna(0).where(df['End'].to_numpy()[:,None] >= [df.columns[1:]])
```

Or safer when your other data is not `NaN`:

```
df.iloc[:,1:] = np.where(df['End'].to_numpy()[:,None] >= [df.columns[1:]],
                         df.iloc[:,1:].fillna(0), df.iloc[:,1:])
```

Output:

```
       End  2022-01  2022-02  2022-03  2022-04  2022-05  2022-06
0  2022-03      1.0      0.0      0.0      NaN      NaN      NaN
1  2022-05      2.0      3.0      1.0      0.0      0.0      NaN
2  2022-06      0.0      4.0      3.0      2.0      0.0      0.0
```

**Note**: It might be better setting `End` as the index.

Answer (score 2):

Probably not the most elegant solution but can be done using `pd.melt` and `pd.pivot`:

```
melt_df = df.melt(id_vars=["End"])
melt_df.loc[(melt_df["End"] >= melt_df["variable"]) & (melt_df["value"].isnull()), "value"] = 0
```

This makes checking your condition easier. Then you reverse back to get original df format:

```
final_df = melt_df.pivot(index="End", columns="variable", values="value").reset_index()
final_df.columns.name = None

       End  2022-01  2022-02  2022-03  2022-04  2022-05  2022-06
0  2022-03      1.0      0.0      0.0      NaN      NaN      NaN
1  2022-05      2.0      3.0      1.0      0.0      0.0      NaN
2  2022-06      0.0      4.0      3.0      2.0      0.0      0.0
```

Comment: `stack`/`unstack` variant: `df.set_index('End').stack(dropna=False).pipe(lambda s: s.fillna(s.where(s.index.get_level_values(0)<s.index.get_level_values(1), 0))).unstack().reset_index()`

Comment: Thank you for the help but I think the numpy broadcasting solutions better fit the bill.